# Declare and implement overloaded virtual function for each type in template arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, variadic-templates

I declared a set of overloaded virtual functions for each of the types in template argument list:

```cpp
template<typename ... Tails>
class MessageSubscriber
{
public:
    using onMessage = void;
};

template<typename Head, typyname ... Tails>
class MessageSubscriber<Head, Tails...> : public MessageSubscriber<Tails...>
{
public:
    using MessageSubscriber<Tails...>::onMessage;
    virtual void onMessage(Head const& t) = 0;
};
```

And then I'd like to implement these virtual functions in derived class with some default behaviour like this:

```cpp
template<typename ...Tails>
class MessageHandler : public MessageSubscriber<Tails...>
{
public:
    //for each Type T in Tails
    void onMessage(T const& t) override
    {
        m_message_queue.enqueue(t);
    }
private:
    SomeMessageQueue<std::variant<Tails...>> m_message_queue;
};
```

Is it possible to auto generate these implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest a slight reworking of the code? I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do though.

```
template <typename Message>
class MessageSubscriber {
public:
  virtual ~MessageSubscriber() = default;
  virtual void onMessage(const Message &) = 0;
};

template <typename Handler, typename Message>
class MessageHandlerBase : public MessageSubscriber<Message> {
public:
  void onMessage(const Message &m) override {
    static_cast<Handler *>(this)->m_message_queue.enqueue(m);
  }
};

template <typename... Messages>
class MessageHandler : public MessageHandlerBase<MessageHandler<Messages...>, Messages>... {
public:
  template <typename, typename>
  friend class MessageHandlerBase;

private:
  SomeMessageQueue<std::variant<Messages...>> m_message_queue;
};
```

If you keep the declaration of `MessageSubscriber` the same you end up running into all sorts of problems because of inheriting the same class multiple times along the hierarchy.

Comment: Exactly what I want. I used this stupid inheritance hierarchy only because I didn't know we could put "..." outside '<>' to expand the parameter pack like this. Thank you so much!